# Complex and compound sentences

Tags: grammar

I would like to know the difference between the sentences as follow:

I have been to Germany twice.

I have been in Germany twice.

Furthermore, I would like to know the difference between the sentences as follow:

Every day Dan will come home from work and turn on the TV.

Every day Dan comes home from work and turns on the TV.

Best Regards,

Babak

Comment: You should post this as two seperate questions.

Comment: What @MikeBrockington said. I see no connection between the two things being asked about here.

Comment: Sorry. I changed my questions, but I forgot to change the topic.

Answer (score 1):

A compound sentence is a sentence made up of two or more independent clauses joined by a conjunction or punctuation. By "independent clause", we mean a set of words which could be a sentence on their own.

For example, I could write two simple sentences, "Bob is tall. Mary is short." Or I could combine them into one compound sentence, "Bob is tall but Mary is short."

A complex sentence is a sentence that has an independent clause and one or more dependent clauses. That is, a main clause that could stand as a sentence by itself, and one or more other clauses that are not stand-alone sentences. For example, "He was like a dog who thinks he owns the neighborhood." "He was like a dog" is an independent clause. We could leave it at that and it would be a sentence by itself. But "who thinks he owns the neighborhood" is not a stand-alone sentence.

What caused me trouble when I was first learning this is that often what makes the dependent clause not independent is that it has an extra word or two, not that it's missing something. Consider, "After Bob left town, his girlfriend forgot him." "His girlfriend forgot him" is an independent clause. It could be its own sentence. "After Bob left town" is a dependent clause because it is not a valid sentence by itself. But if we just removed the word "after", we'd have "Bob left town", which is a perfectly good sentence.